# xslt fields grouped by their type

Tags: xslt

I have some data that i put in (image, title, text). I ahve 3 different elements in my xslt for each of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:udt="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable" exclude-result-prefixes="udt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <!--
  This prefix is used to generate module specific query strings
  Each querystring or form value that starts with udt_{ModuleId}_param 
  will be added as parameter starting with param
  -->
  <xsl:variable name="prefix_param">udt_<xsl:value-of select="//udt:Context/udt:ModuleId" />_param</xsl:variable>


   <xsl:template match="udt:Data" mode="list">

        <xsl:value-of select="udt:Image" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

        <xsl:value-of select="udt:Title" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

        <xsl:value-of select="udt:Text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/udt:UserDefinedTable">
    <xsl:variable name="currentData" select="udt:Data" />


    <xsl:if test="$currentData">

                <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list">
                </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:if>



  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="EditLink">
    <xsl:if test="udt:EditLink">
      <a href="{udt:EditLink}">
        <img border="0" alt="edit" src="{//udt:Context/udt:ApplicationPath}/images/edit.gif" />
      </a>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to fill these elements each into its own div group, so my end result would be something like this:

```
<div id="images">
    <!--all images here-->
</div>
<div id="title">
    <!--all titles here-->
</div>
<div id="text">
    <!--all texts here-->
</div>
```

Can this be achieved by any kind of grouping or whats the right aproach?

Comment: It would help to show an example of your source document structure.

Answer (score 1):

The concept to use `xsl:value-of` for your 3 element types is wrong,
as this instruction copies only the **content** of these elements,
without XML markup.

Assuming that the only goal is to reorder (group) your elements,
and they are direct descendants of the current element (`udt:Data`),
the task can be done the following way:

```
<xsl:template match="udt:Data">
  <xsl:copy>
    <div id="images">
      <xsl:copy-of select="udt:Image"/>
    </div>
    <div id="title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="udt:Title"/>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
      <xsl:copy-of select="udt:Text"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, this is only a template, not the whole script.

Note that e.g. if these elements were located also at "deeper" descendant levels,
all the above XPath expressions should be prececed with `descendant::`.

And remember about including in your script all namespaces, the script refers to.
They should be declared in `stylesheet` tag.